# maven-surefire-plugin inclusion of Single test is not working

Tags: java, maven, selenium, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

To execute single Test from Maven pom.xml, we can executed it from maven surefire plugin.

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>App.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But, Its not working as of now. Something is missing to declare ? I remember, before few months once I have execute it and it worked.

Console :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< mavenSampleProject01:mavenSampleProjects >--------------
[INFO] Building mavenSampleProjects 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mavenSampleProjects ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Desktop-pc\eclipse-workspace\mavenSampleProjects\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ mavenSampleProjects ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mavenSampleProjects ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Desktop-pc\eclipse-workspace\mavenSampleProjects\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mavenSampleProjects ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ mavenSampleProjects ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.371 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-02T11:58:27+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Make sure the directory-structure fits the expression. With this expression the file must be at root level in sry/test/java (meaning no packages) as far as I know.

Comment: @bish If I define it as like : <include>src/main/java/pg01/App.java</include> than also its not working.

Comment: @glytching I have tried that also, but its not working.

Comment: If you like to execute a single test this can be achieved by giving on command like `mvn -Dtest=FirstTest test` no need to change the pom file for such things.

Comment: @khmarbaise  Thank you. But, I am Executing in Jenkins, from POM.XML

Comment: You can of course give the command line parameters in Jenkins as well. apart from that if you run Jenkins than why do you like to limit the unit tests.? Better is to run all tests..

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes I know there is provision of mvn command too. I do Unit test for some of the Long execution, based on chain flow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide full qualified class name to include it by surefire plugin.
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Alternatively you can use regex like "**/*App.java"

Comment: `**/*App.java` is not a regex pattern. it is a so-called _ant-style path expression_.

Answer (score 0):

Add below plugins to your POM file.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that, **Maven test only runs it from src/test/java package**

**It does not consider to run it from src/main/java**

If it need to consider src/main/java, We have to add `<testSourceDirectory>` element

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/app.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```